# string iterators incompatible boost::tokenizer

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, boost-tokenizer

I have a simple code sample of a class that wraps boost::tokenizer.

**MyTokenizer.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

class MyTokenizer
{
public:
    typedef boost::tokenizer< boost::escaped_list_separator<char> > TokType;

    MyTokenizer(std::string);
    ~MyTokenizer() {};
    void printTok();

private:
    const TokType tok_;

};
```

**MyTokenizer.cpp**

```
#include "MyTokenizer.h"


MyTokenizer::MyTokenizer(std::string input) :
tok_(input)
{
    std::cout << "Created tokenizer from: " << input << std::endl;
    for (TokType::iterator it = tok_.begin(); it != tok_.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
}

void MyTokenizer::printTok(){
    std::cout << "printing tokens" << std::endl;
    for (TokType::iterator it = tok_.begin(); it != tok_.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "MyTokenizer.h"

int main(void){
    std::string input("a,b,c");
    MyTokenizer tok(input);
    tok.printTok();
}
```

When I run this example it makes it through the constructor fine, printing the expected tokens in the loop but on the call to printTok() it gives this error

[image]

It seems like I cant create an iterator of MyTokenizer outside of the constructor.

**Edit**

I changed the printTok() method to be even simpler while still throwing the same error it now looks like this.

```
void MyTokenizer::printTok(){
    TokType::iterator it = tok_.begin();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I fixed this myself.  The problem was that the string I built my tokenizer from was being de-allocated at the end of the constructor.  I fixed it by storing a copy of the input string in my class and building my tokenizer from this string.